# Вывести первые буквы слов предложения в string

Tags: c++, строки

Нужно вывести первые буквы слов заданного предложения s. То есть, что бы на выводе были буквы "С р c в с п б к с "

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string s;
    s = "Создайте рядок, содержащий в себе первые буквы каждого слова заданого предлоджения.";
    cout << "ИСХОДНЫЙ РЯДОК:" << endl << s << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вопрос задайте так, чтобы он был похож на вопрос. Ваше  сообщение звучит как заказ

Comment: @ARHovsepyan для "заказа" нужно еще фото и пистолет

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    string s;
    s = "Создайте рядок, содержащий в себе первые буквы каждого слова заданого предлоджения.";
    cout <<s[0]<<" ";
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
        if (s[i] == ' ')
            cout <<s[i+1]<<" ";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: откуда гарантия,  что между  словами только один пробел или  строка начинается не с пробела или в конце строки нет несколько пробелов?...

Comment: Что здесь делают `#include <math.h>` и `#include <stdio.h>`? При этом для `setlocale` нужно `#include <clocale>`.

Answer (score 3):

```
size_t pos = 0;
const char del = ' ';
while (pos != s.npos) {
    pos = s.find_first_not_of(del, pos);
    if (pos == s.npos) break;
    std::cout << s[pos] << del;
    pos = s.find(del, pos + 1);
}
```

Как записать в строку вместо вывода, выполняйте сами

Comment: А если разделителей несколько (не только пробел)? Т.е. лучше использовать `char *del = " \t,:";` или что-то подобное

Comment: @avp, согласен,  но это уже зависит от требования задачи. В данной задаче говорится о получении первого символа, но не говорится какой он не должен быть

Comment: @avp, данный код никак не выводит последный символ перед пробелом. Запятая стоит в конце лексемы, а не в начале

Answer (score 2):

погугли есть какая-то функция которая принимает ПОДстроку и ищет ее в другой строке, и возвращает индекс на нее, т.е. тебе надо в эту функцию передать " ", и получившее вставить сюда: s[<то что получилось>]